# javascript "polymorphic callable objects"

Tags: javascript

I saw [this article on polymorphic callable objects](http://ajaxian.com/archives/javascript-tips-for-rookies-and-gurus) and was trying to get it to work, however it seems that they are not really polymorphic, or at least they do not respect the prototype chain.

This code prints `undefined`, not `"hello there"`.

Does this method not work with prototypes, or am I doing something wrong?

```
var callableType = function (constructor) {
  return function () {
    var callableInstance = function () {
      return callableInstance.callOverload.apply(callableInstance, arguments);
    };
    constructor.apply(callableInstance, arguments);
    return callableInstance;
  };
};

var X = callableType(function() {
    this.callOverload = function(){console.log('called!')};
});

X.prototype.hello = "hello there";

var x_i = new X();
console.log(x_i.hello);
```

Comment: I just impressed by your portrait and name. I suppose his name Shuren Zhou.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd need to change this:

```
var X = callableType(function() {
    this.callOverload = function(){console.log('called!')};
});
```

to this:

```
var X = new (callableType(function() {
    this.callOverload = function(){console.log('called!')};
}));
```

Notice the `new` as well as the parentheses around the `callableType` invocation.

The parentheses allows `callableType` to be invoked and return the function, which is used as the constructor for `new`.

---

**EDIT:**

```
var X = callableType(function() {
    this.callOverload = function() {
        console.log('called!')
    };
});

var someType = X();      // the returned constructor is referenced
var anotherType = X();   // the returned constructor is referenced

someType.prototype.hello = "hello there";  // modify the prototype of
anotherType.prototype.hello = "howdy";     //    both constructors

var some_i = new someType();           // create a new "someType" object
console.log(some_i.hello, some_i);

var another_i = new anotherType();     // create a new "anotherType" object
console.log(another_i.hello, another_i);

someType();      // or just invoke the callOverload
anotherType();
```

I really don't know how/where/why you'd use this pattern, but I suppose there's some good reason.

Comment: Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, but this seems to break being able to call the instance—calling `x_i()` throws an exception along the lines of "object not function".

Comment: @luxun: By using `new` inline like that, you're invoking the function returned form `callableType` immediately as a constructor. I think what you're missing is that your code was adding to the prototype of `X` instead of to the constructor returned from `X`. The way I have it, `X` becomes the constructor itself, but you could reference it in another variable instead. I'll add an update.

Comment: Okay, I see. I actually thought it would make the *instance* callable, but I see this is not the case.