# How do I inherit javascript functions ?

Tags: javascript, oop, function, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

```
// Don't break the function prototype.
// pd - https://github.com/Raynos/pd
var proto = Object.create(Function.prototype, pd({
  "prop": 42
}));

var f = function() { return "is a function"; };
f.__proto__ = proto;

console.log(f.hasOwnProperty("prop")); // false
console.log(f.prop); // 42
console.log(f()); // "is a function"
```

[`.__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Proto) is non-standard and deprecated.

How am I supposed to inherit prototypically creating an object but having that object be a function.

`Object.create` returns an Object not a Function.

`new Constructor` returns an Object not a Function.

**Motivation:** - A cross-browser `finherit`

```
var finherit = function (parent, child) {
    var f = function() { 
        parent.apply(this, arguments);
        child.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    f.__proto__ = parent;
    Object.keys(child).forEach(function _copy(key) {
        f[key] = child[key];
    });
    return f;
};
```

I don't believe this is possible, so we should probably propose a `Function.create` to the es-discuss mailing list

```
/*
  Creates a new function whose prototype is proto.
  The function body is the same as the function fbody.
  The hash of propertydescriptors props is passed to defineproperties just like
  Object.create does.
*/
Function.create = (function() {
  var functionBody = function _getFunctionBody(f) {
    return f.toString().replace(/.+\{/, "").replace(/\}$/, "");
  };
  var letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");

  return function _create(proto, fbody, props) {
    var parameters = letters.slice(0, fbody.length);
    parameters.push(functionBody(fbody));
    var f = Function.apply(this, parameters);
    f.__proto__ = proto;
    Object.defineProperties(f, props);
    return f;
  };
})();
```

[Related es-discuss mail](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2011-September/016743.html)

As mentioned in the es-discuss thread there exists a ES:strawman [`<|`](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proto_operator) prototype operator which would allow for this.

Let's see what it would look like using `<|`

```
var f1 = function () {
  console.log("do things");
};

f1.method = function() { return 42; };

var f2 = f1 <| function () {
  super();
  console.log("do more things");
}
console.log(f1.isPrototypeOf(f2)); // true
console.log(f2()); // do things do more things
console.log(f2.hasOwnProperty("method")); // false
console.log(f2.method()); // 42
```

Comment: `console.log(f.apply);` will return `undefined`... so that way is not optimal in any way... still thinking about an alternative.

Comment: @FelixKling I forgot that I should inherit from `Function.prototype` thanks

Comment: There was [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564481/javascript-polymorphic-callable-objects) I encounter a while back where the asker referenced [this article](http://ajaxian.com/archives/javascript-tips-for-rookies-and-gurus) which showed a pattern for creating *"polymorphic callable objects"*. Not sure if it's what you're after, but may be worth a look.

Comment: @patrick_dw doesn't really help but thank you ;)

Comment: @O_._O change your name back ¬_¬

Comment: I don't know who this O_._O character is , but if you're talking to Ӫ_._Ӫ, my lease ran out on the old name, but you may informally address me as *"the artist formerly known as patrick dw"*.

Comment: @patrick_dw your an idiot. o/

Comment: Please tell me that you're not just now figuring that out!

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ I was thinking the same thing, Raynos. `:p`

Comment: Oh sweet. I had seen the *prototype for* operator a while ago when reading about the proposed extensions to the object literal syntax, but didn't pay very close attention. ES5 is nice and all, but there's so much cool stuff proposed right now, I just hope that they crank it out without making us wait too long.

Comment: I really don't think this is solvable. I'm with you 100% though... great thought, not really possible. Given a handful of years maybe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I hope that I'm understanding this right.

I believe you want a functor that's both an instance of a predefined prototype (yes, a class, just not a classic class) as well as directly callable? Right? If so, then this makes perfect sense and is very powerful and flexible (especially in a highly asynchronous environment like JavaScript). **Sadly there is no way to do it *elegantly* in JavaScript without manipulating `__proto__`**. You can do it by factoring out an anonymous function and copying all of the references to all of the methods (which seems to be the direction you were heading) to act as a proxy class. The downsides to this are...

1. It's very costly in terms of runtime.
2. `(functorObj instanceof MyClass)` will never be `true`.
3. Properties will not be directly accessible (if they were all assigned by reference this would be a different story, but primitives are assigned by value). This can be solved with accessors via `defineProperty` or simply named accessor methods if necessary (it appears that that is what you're looking for, just add all properties to the functor with `defineProperty` via getters/setters instead of just functions if you don't need cross-engine support/backwards compatability).
4. You're likely to run into edge cases where final native prototypes (like Object.prototype or Array.prototype [if you're inheriting that]) may not function as expected.
5. Calling `functorObj(someArg)` will *always* make the `this` context be the object, regardless of if it's called `functorObj.call(someOtherObj, someArg)` (this is not the case for method calls though)
6. Because the functor object is created at request time, it will be locked in time and manipulating the initial prototype will not affect the allocated functor objects like a normal object would be affected (modifying MyClass.prototype will not affect any functor objects and the reverse is true as well).

If you use it gently though, none of this should be a big deal.

In your prototype of your class define something like...

```
// This is you're emulated "overloaded" call() operator.
MyClass.prototype.execute = function() {
   alert('I have been called like a function but have (semi-)proper access to this!');
};

MyClass.prototype.asFunctor = function(/* templateFunction */) {
   if ((typeof arguments[0] !== 'function') && (typeof this.execute !== 'function'))
      throw new TypeError('You really should define the calling operator for a functor shouldn\'t you?');
   // This is both the resulting functor proxy object as well as the proxy call function
   var res = function() {
      var ret;
      if (res.templateFunction !== null)
         // the this context here could be res.asObject, or res, or whatever your goal is here
         ret = res.templateFunction.call(this, arguments);
      if (typeof res.asObject.execute === 'function')
         ret = res.asObject.execute.apply(res.asObject, arguments);
      return ret;
   };
   res.asObject = this;
   res.templateFunction = (typeof arguments[0] === 'function') ? arguments[0] : null;
   for (var k in this) {
      if (typeof this[k] === 'function') {
         res[k] = (function(reference) {
            var m = function() {
               return m.proxyReference.apply((this === res) ? res.asObject : this, arguments);
            };
            m.proxyReference = reference;
            return m;
         })(this.asObject[k]);
      }
   }
   return res;
};
```

Resulting usage would look something like...

```
var aobj = new MyClass();
var afunctor = aobj.asFunctor();
aobj.someMethodOfMine(); // << works
afunctor.someMethodOfMine(); // << works exactly like the previous call (including the this context).
afunctor('hello'); // << works by calling aobj.execute('hello');

(aobj instanceof MyClass) // << true
(afunctor instanceof MyClass) // << false
(afunctor.asObject === aobj) // << true

// to bind with a previous function...
var afunctor = (new MyClass()).asFunctor(function() { alert('I am the original call'); });
afunctor() // << first calls the original, then execute();
// To simply wrap a previous function, don't define execute() in the prototype.
```

You could even chain bind countless other objects/functions/etc until the cows came home. Just refactor the proxy call a bit.

Hope that helps. Oh, and of course you could change the factory flow so that a constructor called without the `new` operator then instantiates a new object and returns the functor object. However you prefer (you could surely do it other ways too).

Finally, to have any function become the execution operator for a functor in a bit more elegant of a manner, just make the proxy function a method of `Function.prototype` and pass it the object to wrap if you want to do something like (you would have to swap `templateFunction` with `this` and `this` with the argument of course)...

```
var functor = (function() { /* something */ }).asFunctor(aobj);
```

Comment: Cool. I'd never heard of functors. I'm definitely gonna name my next dog functor.

Comment: This is really a pseudo functor (yes, funny name) proxying everything. It's a sloppy way to make it happen. Some languages support this natively. If EMCAScript5 allowed `__proto__` manipulation (or an equivalent alternative standard), **or** operator overloads, so would JavaScript. Sadly it doesn't. For all it's power and flexibility... sigh.

Comment: @mr.stobbe could you have a stab at using ES6 proxies to do this instead? (Works in chrome & FF). Alternatively you could cheat and pretend `<|` exists (`protoOf = function (proto, thing) { thing.__proto__ = proto; }`)

Comment: @Raynos - Yes. In fact quite a bit of this could have been written to support ES5 features but I purposely avoided them to show how it can be done in a completely backwards compatibly way (this would likely be supported by all current and recently outmoded engines). It was just to show that it can be done. The frustration of the question here was really around what's become a gap between ES specs so I wanted to provide a solution that would work everywhere.

Comment: @mr.stobbe The main frustration is that ES5 can't do this and `.__protot__` is a non-standard deprecated hack that's not part of ES. You can't do it with ES5 features

Comment: @Raynos Yes. Sorry... should have said "between implementations". Sorry, it was late.

Answer (score 0):

With ES6 it's possible to inherit from `Function`, see (duplicate) question

[javascript class inherit from Function class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988566/javascript-class-inherit-from-function-class)

```
default export Attribute extends Function {
...
}
```