# javascript class inherit from Function class

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance, function-object

I like that in javascript, I can create a function, and then add further methods and attributes to that function

```
myInstance = function() {return 5}
myInstance.attr = 10
```

I would like to create a class to generate these objects. I assume I have to inherit from the Function base class.

In other words, I would like to:

```
var myInstance = new myFunctionClass()
var x = myInstance()
// x == 5
```

But I don't know how to create the myFunctionClass. I have tried the following, but it does not work:

```
var myFunctionClass = function() {Function.call(this, "return 5")}
myFunctionClass.prototype = new Function()
myInstance = new myFunctionClass()
myInstance()
// I would hope this would return 5, but instead I get
// TypeError: Property 'myInstance' of object #<Object> is not a function
```

I also tried the more complicated (and more proper?) inheritance method found here: [How to "properly" create a custom object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript/1598077), with no more luck. I have also tried using the util.inherits(myFunctionClass, Function) found in node.js. Still no luck

I have exhausted Google, and therefore feel that I must be missing something fundamental or obvious. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not possible to do this (using `[[prototype]]`) in ECMAScript 3rd Edition. I do not know if there is a tricky method in 5th Edition that allows this, or not. "Conventional" methods -- e.g. that used in jQuery -- copy the individual properties over from a "prototype", without using prototype inheritance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your trying to inherit from `Function`. This is a right pain to do. I suggest you do the following instead

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EBGyP/6/)

```
var Proto = Object.create(Function.prototype);
Object.extend(Proto, {
  constructor: function (d) {
    console.log("construct, argument : ", d);
    this.d = d; 
    // this is your constructor logic
  },
  call: function () {
    console.log("call", this.d);
    // this get's called when you invoke the "function" that is the instance
    return "from call";
  },
  method: function () {
    console.log("method");
    // some method
    return "return from method";
  },
  // some attr
  attr: 42
});
```

You want to create a prototype object that forms the basis of your "class". It has your generic methods/attributes. It also has a constructor that gets invoked on object construction and a call method that gets invoked when you call the function

```
var functionFactory = function (proto) {
  return function () {
    var f = function () {
      return f.call.apply(f, arguments);      
    };
    Object.keys(proto).forEach(function (key) {
      f[key] = proto[key];
    });
    f.constructor.apply(f, arguments);
    return f;
  }
}
```

A function factory takes a prototype object and returns a factory for it. The returned function when called will give you a new function object that "inherits" from your prototype object.

```
var protoFactory = functionFactory(proto);
var instance = protoFactory();
```

Here you create your factory and then create your instance.

However this isn't proper prototypical OO. we are just shallow copying properties of a prototype into a new object. So changes to the prototype will not reflect back to the original object.

If you want real prototypical OO then you need to use a hack.

```
var f = function () {
  // your logic here
};
f.__proto__ = Proto;
```

Notice how we use the non-standard deprecated `.__proto__` *and* we are mutating the value of `[[Prototype]]` at run-time which is considered evil.

Comment: This is almost the solution I was looking for. However, how do I access attributes of the instance from within methods? `this` does not work; I thought putting `that=this` in the constructor and then referencing `that.attribute` would work. But `that` always points to the most recently created instance, not to the instance from which I am calling the method.

Comment: @dgreisen `this` works inside methods and inside the constructor `this` works, and inside the `call` method `this` works. However I don't call the constructor for you, you have to do that yourself. I've edited the code so the constructor gets called

Comment: @Raynos, Thanks for the response. My code calls the constructor, so I don't think that is the problem. Problem illustration: In live example add to constructor: `this.d=d;`; modify call to `console.log("call", this.d);`; add at end: `instance.call();`. instance.call() correctly logs 'call data'. instance() logs 'call undefined'.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `this` refers to a function's owner. The owner of instance.call() is instance -> `this` refers to instance. But the owner of instance() itself is window -> `this` points to window, not instance. Is there a keyword that points to instance from within instance, so I can access instance.d from instance()?

Answer (score 1):

JS does not allow a constructor to return a function, even though functions are objects.  So you cant have an instantiation of a prototype that is itself executable. (Am I right in this? please correct if I'm not, it's an interesting question).

Though you could do a factory function:

```
var makeCoolFunc = function() {
  var f = function() { return 5 };
  f.a = 123;
  f.b = 'hell yes!'
  return f;
};

var func = makeCoolFunc();
var x = func();
```

Comment: "*JS does not allow a constructor to return a function*" - I don't think that's correct. You can return a function object from a constructor function.

Comment: Well, it may return it, but if you return something other than `this` then the return value wont have the constructors prototype, right?  So there isn't much point. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mDxhg/

Comment: You can return a function from a constructor. You however cannot return an instantiation of a prototype with an internal `[[Call]]` property

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `Function` and pass the wanted function body as String to the super constructor. The context of the function can be accessed with `arguments.callee`.

Example for an observable Attribute class:

```
    export default class Attribute extends Function  {

    constructor(defaultValue){
        super("value", "return arguments.callee.apply(arguments);");
        this.value = defaultValue;
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
        this.changeListeners = [];
    }

    apply([value]){
        if(value!==undefined){
           if(value!==this.value){
               var oldValue = this.value;
               this.value=value;
               this.changeListeners.every((changeListener)=>changeListener(oldValue, value));
           }
        }
        return this.value;
    }

    clear(){
        this.value=undefined;
    }

    reset(){
        this.value=this.defaultValue;
    }

    addChangeListener(listener){
        this.changeListeners.push(listener);
    }

    removeChangeListener(listener){
        this.changeListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    clearChangeListeners(){
        this.changeListeners = [];
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
import Attribute from './attribute.js';

var name= new Attribute();
name('foo'); //set value of name to 'foo'

name.addChangeListener((oldValue, newValue)=>{
    alert('value changed from ' +oldValue+ ' to ' +newValue);
});
alert(name()); //show value of name: 'foo'

name('baa'); //set value of name to new value 'baa' and trigger change listener
```