# How to make JavaScript function inheritance work right

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I've got a problem. I'm working on a fairly large JavaScript project, and I'm learning how to use OOP. It's kind of weird in JS, as I'm sure you know.

So here's what I'm trying to do: I've got a base 'class', that I call `AbstractAnimal`. I've got another class called `Animals`. Inside of the `Animals` class I have three groups, called `Man`, `Monkey`, and `Elephant`. I want each of those groups to inherit `AbstractAnimal`, but to be their own functions, not connected to `AbstractAnimal`.

I was originally doing that like this:

```
Animals.prototype.Man = AbstractAnimal;
Animals.prototype.Monkey = AbstractAnimal; //etc...
```

However, that doesn't do what I need it to do, sadly. Here's why:

```
AbstractAnimal.prototype.clicked = function() { console.log("clicked") };
//If I change Man...
animals.Man.clicked = function() { console.log("HA!"); };
//Monkey is effected too...
animals.Monkey.clicked();
//Console: "HA!"
```

In the example above, when Monkey is clicked I would want the console to say "clicked". When Man is clicked, it should say "HA!".

So I found something that I thought would do it over here: [javascript class inherit from Function class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988566/javascript-class-inherit-from-function-class)

And it almost worked, but not quite. Here's a reduced test case: http://jsfiddle.net/9KRJk/2/

Could'ja help me out? Thanks!

P.S. No, actually, the whole animal thing is metaphorical, I'm not actually programming a zoo. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know if I quite understand your problem, but maybe you're complicating things too much or maybe you're missing some concepts, but your prototype chain can be represented like this:

```
// Extends helper
Function.prototype.extends = function( parent ) {
  this.prototype = Object.create( parent.prototype );
};

function Animal() {}
Animal.prototype = {
  clicked: function() {
    console.log('animal');
  }
};

function Man() {}
Man.extends( Animal );
Man.prototype.clicked = function() {
  console.log('man');
};

function Monkey() {}
Monkey.extends( Animal );
Monkey.prototype.clicked = function() {
  console.log('monkey');
};

var animal = new Animal();
animal.clicked(); //=> 'animal'

var man = new Man();
man.clicked(); //=> 'man'

var monkey = new Monkey();
monkey.clicked(); //=> 'monkey'
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! That wasn't quite what I needed, but it gave me the direction that I needed. And my code's a bit cleaner now! For future people, this also helped me find the answer: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2184-Object-create-Improves-Constructor-Based-Inheritance-In-Javascript-It-Doesn-t-Replace-It.htm