# Local scope Function prototype override

Tags: javascript

It is trivial to add prototypes to all `Function`s:

```
Function.prototype.foo = function () { return 'bar'; };
(new Function).foo();  // 'bar'
```

However, it is also bad practice to assign things to a global object's prototype, due to cross-module object reliance concerns, partially leading to the demise to earlier versions of *prototype.js*.

Suppose I want all of *my* functions to have the method `foo`. I would do something similar to this:

```
(function () {
    var Fn = Function;
    Fn.prototype.foo = function () { return 'bar'; };

    (new Fn).foo();  // 'bar'
}());

(new Function).foo()  // also 'bar'. this is bad!
```

Unfortunately, this affects `Function`'s prototype as well, because Function was scoped by reference.

The usual "copy value" approach for passing primitive values into IIFEs would also fail, because `Function` itself is an object.

```
(function (Fn) {
    Fn.prototype.foo = function () { return 'bar'; };

    (new Fn).foo();  // 'bar'
}(Function));


Function.foo  // function () { return 'bar'; }
```

Given these examples, is it true that it is impossible to extend *selected* functions' prototypes, without affecting all other functions outside my scope?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988566/javascript-class-inherit-from-function-class

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev "Your [*sic*] trying to inherit from Function. This is a right pain to do." Well... that's a shame.

Answer (score 1):

Create a prototype for your custom functions using `new` keyword.

That way, the original `Function.prototype` will not change:

```
(function (BaseFunction) {  
   var CustomFunction = function () { };
   CustomFunction.prototype = new BaseFunction();
   CustomFunction.prototype.foo = function () { return 'bar'; };
   console.log((new CustomFunction()).foo()); // 'bar'
})(Function);
console.log((new Function).foo); //undefined
```

Comment: What's `BaseFunction` for?

Comment: @RocketHazmat typo, it is a reference to original `Function`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work.  Your `CustomFunction` objects won't be callable as functions.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that's not possible. You could try something like this, to set more prototypes at once (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZgM8A/):

```
var ns = {};

(function(ns){
    var local = {};

    local.func1 = function() {
        this.p = "func1";
    }

    local.func2 = function() {
        this.p = "func2";
    }

    var proto = {
        name : "test"
    }

    for (var prop in local){
        if (local.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof local[prop] === "function"){
            local[prop].prototype = proto
        }
    }

    console.log(new local.func1());
    console.log(new local.func2());

}(ns))
```