# Are there efficient ways to use `__proto__` or `setPrototypeOf()` in javascript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance, prototype-chain

MDN has a huge scary warning about modifying the prototype in your code:

> Changing the `[[Prototype]]` of an object is, by the nature of how
>   modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, a very slow
>   operation, in ***every*** browser and JavaScript engine. The effects on
>   performance of altering inheritance are subtle and far-flung, and are
>   not limited to simply the time spent in the `Object.setPrototypeOf(...)` statement,
>   but may extend to ***any*** code that has access to any object whose
>   `[[Prototype]]` has been altered. If you care about performance you
>   should avoid setting the `[[Prototype]]` of an object. Instead, create a
>   new object with the desired `[[Prototype]]` using [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).
>
> —[MDN > JavaScript > Object.setPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)

I’m wondering if there are any situations where you can modify an object’s prototype *without* causing cascading optimization effects that kill your program's performance. It seems like there should be. For example if you only modify the prototype right after the object is created (and before its used by anything else). But I imagine this is very engine-dependent.

So does anyone know if there are efficient ways to modify an object’s prototype?

**Edit:** The motivation for this question comes from a desire to create objects that actually inherit from `Function`. And the only way I know how to do that is by modifying the prototype of a function. See the very bottom of Raynos’s answer here: [javascript class inherit from Function class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988566/javascript-class-inherit-from-function-class)

Comment: You could do `Object.assign(Object.create(obj), { obj2, obj3, obj4 })` which will create a new object with the prototypes of obj. I believe it comes from a book by Eric Elliot. It nets better memory footprint. I wish I could give you a better definition, but it has something to do with Object.create() doesn't actually instantiate a new object, so it's faster than getting the prototypes from another way. Try Googling something like "Object.create memory performance". I think you might find lots of good material.

Comment: Any question including the terms "efficiency" and "performance" should include benchmarks for the comparisons of the various patterns of code which were tried;  the code from which the benchmarks were derived; and the results of the code at different browsers. Else the inquiry is based on pure speculation, where a definitive answer is affirmatively possible.

Comment: Btw, there [is a way to create objects inheriting from `Function` without setting the prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36871498/1048572), but setting the prototype is much more comfortable still. And yes, "*if you only modify the prototype right after the object is created*" should indeed be an (or: the only) exception to this rule, however I cannot prove it.

Comment: See also [Why is mutating the \[\[prototype\]\] of an object bad for performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23807805/1048572) for details.

Answer (score 3):

> The motivation for this question comes from a desire to create objects that actually inherit from Function.

It seems what you are trying to do is the following:

- Create *new* objects
- Set these objects' prototype (or `__proto__` property) to refer to [Fuction.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype) such that they inherit properties from `Function.prototype`, e.g.:

  - `.apply`
  - `.call`
  - `.bind`

You should never need to *change* any object’s prototype as long as you can correctly set it to the desired reference at the time the object is created.

---

### Answer One: How to Set an Object's Prototype

You can set any object’s prototype upon creation using `Object.create()`. Note that assigning any object's prototype to `Function.prototype` will *not* cause the object to be a callable function. But if you still wanted to assign the prototype to refer to `Function.prototype`, or to some other object, you could do the following:

```
var obj1 = Object.create(Function.prototype);
```

This will:

- Create a new object, `obj1`
- Set its prototype (or `__proto__` property) to refer to `Function.prototype` or whatever object you pass in as the argument

  - i.e., it will delegate failed property lookups to `Function.prototype` via the [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) (this is what a JavaScript prototype is and what `__proto__` refers to: a place to delegate failed property lookups)

This does *not* require you to use `Object.setPrototypeOf()` to change an existing object's prototype because it assigns the prototype at the moment the object is created. See MDN docs for [Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) for more examples and info -- this does not carry the same scary warnings as `setPrototypeOf()`. You can use `Object.create()` to set any new object's prototype.

---

### Answer Two: Functions are Already Objects

That said, if you want an object that behaves like a function, you can simply create a function. A function is still an object, but with additional function-specific properties and behaviors; you can still treat it like an object by assigning properties to it. If you're looking to create a function that also acts like an object, or an object that can also do the same things as a function, then a function already does that. You can do things like:

```
var func = function() { return 'hello world'; }; // func is a function
func.property1 = 'foo'; // func is also an object
func.property2 = 'bar';
```

The best solution to your question may be to take advantage of the fact that functions are, in fact, already objects with added function-abilities.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to let an object that is not callable inherit the `Function.prototype` methods. And `Object.create` cannot create callable objects.

Comment: Agreed! That said, it’s still important to know how to use Object.create() to assign a new object’s prototype so I think it’s worth including