# Collection/Instance objects style vie javascript without proto

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I'm trying to make classical Collection/Instance model via javascript. So Collection object has some method for working with full collection and ((new Collection()) instanceof Instance) has methods to work with the instance. My code is rather simple.

```
var Collection = function Collection() {
  this.message = "collection";
  var I = Instance.bind(null, this);
  I.__proto__ = this;
  return I;
};
Collection.prototype = {
  collectionMethod: function () {
    console.log(this.message);
  }
};

var Instance = function Instance(collection) {
  this.collection = collection;
  this.message = "instance";
};
Instance.prototype = {
  instanceMethod: function () {
    console.log(this.message);
  }
};

// Test exec (values are like expected);

var C = new Collection();
var i = new C();
C.collectionMethod(); // collection
i.instanceMethod(); // instance
i.collection.collectionMethod(); // collection
C.newMethod(); // TypeError
i.newMethod(); // TypeError
Collection.prototype.newMethod = Instance.prototype.newMethod = function () {
  console.log("newMethod: " + this.message);
}
C.newMethod(); // newMethod: collection
i.newMethod(); // newMethod: instance
```

But i don't want to use proto because it's not a part of standart and doesn't work in IE at all. Is there any way around in this case?

---

Some explanations about what's all about. For example you have a collection of users. And you want to be able find the user and create new one.

So you create new collection like

```
var User = new Collection();
```

Then you create new instance like.

```
var me = new User({name: "alex"});
```

And now you find this instance like

```
User.find_by_name("alex"); // === me
```

Also (in fact this is the main reason i'm doing this way instead of just creating something like `User.new` function to use it like `var me = User.new({name: "alex"});`) you can know who I am doing something like (if you for example have also `var Dog = new Collection()`)

```
me instanceof Dog // false
me instanceof User // true
```

Comment: So you're trying to do inheritance? Why `__proto__` and `bind`? I don't get it... You can use `Collection.prototype = Object.create(Instance.prototype)` if I understand correctly...

Comment: This is not inheritance (at least as i understand this term). I need Collection be both constructor function for Instance and object with a lot of "static" methods. So i can do something like.
var C = new Collection();
C.doSmth();
var i = new C();
C instanceof Collection
i instanceof C; // true
i instanceof Instance; // true

Comment: `var Instance = function Instance(collection) {` is a named function expression - those are [bad and should be avoided](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I thought it's good practice because of stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So seems like it's impossible for now. More information can be found here.

[How do I inherit javascript functions ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539148/how-do-i-inherit-javascript-functions)

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
var I = Instance.bind(null, this);
I.__proto__ = this;
return I;
```

really doesn't make much sense.  Function.bind creates a new **function**, so anyone calling your Collection function, in any way, will get back a *function*, not an object whose prototype is set to the function's prototype.

In general, if you want to create an object whose prototype is set to a specific object, you **don't** set `__proto__` since that's not standard, as you stated.  The best way is to just use Object.create (which is shimable if you want to support IE8).

```
var I = Object.create(this);
```

---

Also, the reason you're getting errors on `newMethod` is because you're trying to call them *before* you add them to the prototype:

```
Collection.prototype.newMethod = Instance.prototype.newMethod = function () {
  console.log("newMethod: " + this.message);
}
C.newMethod(); // should work now
i.newMethod(); // should work now
```

Comment: But i need (new Collection()) returning a function, because in the next step i do (new C()) and this should be a new Instance in the collection (but not the new Collection).

About exception. The code snippet works how it's expected. And TypeErrors are expected too.

Comment: @Ximik - it sounds like you're doing some really non-standard, weird stuff.  I'd recommend you take a step back and really learn the ins and outs of js before trying to do something like this.

Comment: I've added some explanations to the question.  Yes, of course i can do something like
var Collection = function Collection() {
  this.new = new Instance(this);
  ...
}

And then var me = User.new(). But js is prototype language and this is not like it should be in prototype languages (and i don't understand  what's wrong with proto redefining or callable objects).